# Does this variable have a HyperGeometric distribution?

Tags: probability

David has 100 cards in his right pocket: 70 black, 20 blue and 10 white.
in each time David chose randomly one card, and move it to his left pocket.

What is the distribution of the number of blue cards that left in David's **right** pocket after $n$ times.

1. HyperGeometric
2. Geometric
3. Binomial
4. None of the above

I saw the solutions, and it should be 1.HyperGeometric.
But I don't understand how it can be HyperGeometric.

because lets say $n=2$. then if it is HyperGeometric distribution then the value 0 should be with probability $>0$. But here the only possible values are 20,19,18.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might as well assume that the $n$ cards are moved **simultaneously**. So we have $20$ blue and $80$ non-blue. We are choosing $n$ cards to be moved. Equivalently, we are (immplicitly) choosing $100-n$ cards to stay in the right pocket. Let $m=100-n$.

The probability exactly $k$ of the $m$ "chosen" (by neglect) are blue is 
$$\frac{\binom{20}{k}\binom{80}{m-k}}{\binom{100}{m}}.\tag{1}$$
For there are $\binom{100}{m}$ equally likely ways to "choose" $m$ cards. We can choose $k$ blue cards in $\binom{20}{k}$ ways, and for each such way we can choose $m-k$ non-blue in $\binom{80}{m-k}$ ways.

If $X$ is the number of blue cards that remain in the right pocket, then $\Pr(X=k)$ is given by Expression (1). This is a standard "hypergeometric" expression.

Comment: but this is the distribution of the number of blue cards that was moved to the left pocket? isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mistook my left and my right. Same idea works, will fix.

Comment: I can Understand that  distribution of the number of blue cards that was moved to the left pocket, is hypergeometric. But what I dont understand as I said before is How is it posible that the distribution of the number of blue cards that left in david's right pocket after n times. is hypergeometric? isn't hypergeometric has to be able to get the value 0 at a positive probability?

Comment: It all depends on $m$. Take $k=0$. If $m \le 80$, that is, we remove $20$ or more cards, then the probability that $X=0$ is non-zero. If $m \gt 80$, that is, we remove $19$ or fewer cards, then the binomial coefficient $\binom{80}{m}$ is $0$.